# Which method to amortize my single family rental and what else do I need to know?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, rental-property, amortization, depreciation

I am renting out my primary residence (outside the US) for about $1400/mo., which method to amortize my single family rental on my 1040 and what else do I need to know to correctly amortize? I started renting it out in 2017 but we bought it in 2003 in case that matters.

Comment: How is it primary residence if you're renting it? Anyway, amortization rules differ by country, is it safe to guess you're in USA?

Comment: I am reporting the rental to the I.R.S. in a 1040, the rental is not located in the u.s. I'd prefer not to say where but I convert the currency to u.s. dollars when reporting the rental so assume all is in dollars. I actually bought the residence in dollars.

Comment: The currency doesn't matter, but the location does. Are you a US tax resident?

Comment: No, I am an expat who lives permanently outside the u.s.

Comment: Sorry, you're a US expat living outside the US? Are you a US citizen/green card holder? Why are you filing 1040 with the IRS if you're not a tax resident?

Comment: Sorry, I got my term mixed up (I thought expat meant that I just don't live in the u.s.) I am a u.s. citizen, I just live outside of the u.s. for many years. I report because it's the law.

Comment: Did you not depreciate the unit on your 2017 or any subsequent year tax returns? You should be using the same method as you used previously.

Comment: US Expat is correct term.  And to be clear, "primary residence" normally means "where you personally live" - you don't mean that, right?  You are renting a house that is not where you currently live (and is outside the US), and live in some other house, in that country or in another?

Comment: I never amortized. I didn't know how to do it. I usually get a refund so it didn't seem like it mattered. Was I able to have gotten a larger refund if I'd have amortized in the past? I plugged it in the tax software this year and the refund stayed the same amount.

Comment: Yes Joe, it used to be my primary residence, about 5.5. years ago but now it's a rental

Comment: Depreciation means taking the total value of the asset (house) and reducing your income by some amount per year - so for example if house cost you $100k, if you depreciate over 20 years, then each year reduce by $5k your income, but also reduce the cost basis of the house $5k (so eventually after 20 years cost basis is 0 - so your return off of the sale of the house is fully taxed).  It can be helpful to depreciate over time (as it reduces your tax each year) since the sale is a capital gain.

Comment: If you started renting it out in 2017 and never depreciated, you lost quite a significant deduction and you may also have problems reporting it now. You may need form 3115 and amend a whole bunch of returns to recapture the deduction for the remaining open years since then.

Comment: Also note "amortize" is not the right word, "depreciate" is; depreciate means to reduce the value of the asset by some amount (on the assumption it loses value over time due to wear/etc.).  Amortize means to split the cost of something over time into payments, so in a way it's similar but not the same exact thing.  See https://homeguides.sfgate.com/can-amortize-rental-property-77587.html

Comment: @user1422331 it may not affect the refund *now* because you're renting at a loss or offsetting the tax with FTC. But when you sell the property, or when you start renting at a profit, this becomes a significant consideration.

Comment: @littleadv, but if all the years I was getting a refund and not paying taxes, what would I have lost? Can you explain where I will lose (or not maximize a deduction) when I sell?

Comment: @Joe, as per my previous comment, could it have helped me get a larger refund each year? I tried plugging in depreciation and the refund amount stayed the same so I didn't bother with it. Am I causing myself long term issues?

Comment: When you sell all the depreciation that you deducted *or was allowed to deduct* will be "recaptured" and taxed at a special rate via sec. 1250. Currently that's 25%. Even if you didn't have a tax benefit when deducting it (which we don't really know how and why), you'll pay that tax. If you had a loss, the depreciation adds to the loss which you can later deduct from sale proceeds or income when at gain. https://www.investopedia.com/terms/d/depreciationrecapture.asp

Comment: @littleadv, can I fix this myself or do I need to use a professional? If I can fix it, how to do it?

Comment: I'd work with a professional. Form 3115, if needed, is not something you can handle without a deep understanding of how it works and what it does. I'm also not sure why you seem to not be getting any tax benefit from the deduction, I suspect you're not reporting it right.

Comment: I asked the tax software help, this is what they replied to me, does it sound correct to you? "The refund stays the same since the amounts for the child tax credit change from non-refundable to refundable when there is less tax to reduce.

It reduces your taxable income 3386. You can see this is in 1040 line 13"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rental property depreciation rules differ depending on the property location. For a US-located **residential** property, you'd be using a MACRS 27.5 years depreciation schedule.

However, in your case, the property is outside the US, and you should be using ADS. The period depends on when you **started** renting out the property:

- On or after January 1st, 2018: ADS 30 years depreciation schedule.
- Before January 1st, 2018: ADS 40 years depreciation schedule.

The change from 40 to 30 years for foreign residential properties was part of the TACJ Act (Note on the differences is [here](https://www.irsstreamlinedprocedures.com/foreign-rental-property-depreciation-irs/)).

Note, that just as with properties in the US, you can only depreciate improvements and not the land. So if your cost of acquisition includes a component for land (i.e.: you also bought the lot, not just the building), you have to prorate the basis accordingly.

Rules differ for commercial properties, but you referred to it as "primary residence", so I'm assuming it's residential.

Some details (and a lot more additional information about renting a foreign property) can be found [here](https://www.eisneramper.com/us-investment-foreign-real-estate-0121/), with some references.